# Is there more shortcuts like %appdata%?

Tags: c#, windows, shortcut

I am trying to manage some data with C# porgram. Data is usually in Desktop or similar basic Windows location. Right now I type full path to specific folders, but I know that there are shortcuts like `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`, `%appdata%`.

Are there more of them? Can I use them in my program?

Comment: Open cmd.exe and type `set` at the prompt to list environment variables. Any of those can be used in the `%xxxx%` form. From within .NET they are accessed via the [`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Yes [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) for paths.

Comment: Just noting that SpecialFolder contains items like "Resources" which cannot be used in the format `%Resources%`, but are usable in a program.

Comment: Be careful. There is, as far as I know, no single, authoritative list of all built-in environment variables supplied by the system, and it certainly varies with versions of Windows. Any answers that claim otherwise should be taken with a grain of salt, because a variable that exists on your system or in your profile isn't necessarily present on your end user's machine. `Environment.SpecialFolder` uses shell paths, which are more reliable, but should not be confused with environment variables.

Comment: Related to: https://superuser.com/questions/217504/is-there-a-list-of-windows-special-directories-shortcuts-like-temp

Answer (score 39):

There are plenty of system variables. Yes, you can use them in your program. To name a few:

| Environment Variable | Path |
| --- | --- |
| `%systemDrive%` or `%homeDrive%` | `C:` |
| `%winDir%` or `%systemRoot%` | `C:\Windows` |
| `%allUsersProfile%` or `%programData%` | `C:\ProgramData` |
| `%comSpec%` | `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` |
| `%homePath%` or `%userProfile%` | `C:\Users\`*username* |
| `%appData%` | `C:\Users\`*username*`\AppData\Roaming` |
| `%localAppData%` | `C:\Users\`*username*`\AppData\Local` |
| `%temp%` or `%tmp%` | `C:\Users\`*username*`\AppData\Local\Temp` |
| `%programFiles%` | `C:\Program Files` |
| `%programFiles(x86)%` | `C:\Program Files (x86)` · *Only in 64-bit Windows* |
| `%commonProgramFiles%` | `C:\Program Files\Common Files` |
| `%commonProgramFiles(x86)%` | `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files` |
| `%public%` | `C:\Users\Public` |

The variables are not case-sensitive.

Comment: Great tips. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Are they case-insensitive?

Comment: @iono They are not case sensitive. Thanks for reformatting. Much clearer now.

Comment: @user2924019 TY! :) How nice is the improved Markdown support on SE! The tables and triple-backtick code blocks are real life-savers.

Answer (score 7):

You can, but you'd probably prefer to use [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx) with the [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration. For instance:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

At the time of writing, the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enumeration has values:

`Desktop, Programs, MyDocuments, Personal, Favorites, Startup, Recent, SendTo, StartMenu, MyMusic, MyVideos, DesktopDirectory, MyComputer, NetworkShortcuts, Fonts, Templates, CommonStartMenu, CommonPrograms, CommonStartup, CommonDesktopDirectory, ApplicationData, PrinterShortcuts, LocalApplicationData, InternetCache, Cookies, History, CommonApplicationData, Windows, System, ProgramFiles, MyPictures, UserProfile, SystemX86, ProgramFilesX86, CommonProgramFiles, CommonProgramFilesX86, CommonTemplates, CommonDocuments, CommonAdminTools, AdminTools, CommonMusic, CommonPictures, CommonVideos, Resources, LocalizedResources, CommonOemLinks, CDBurning`

If you then need to use this info to construct some paths:

```
var somePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
    @"some\path\into\this\folder");
```

Comment: How to get the target path with keeping the environment variables by C# ?

Answer (score 0):

Those are environment variables and you can add new ones yourself or edit them as you like. [Here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) are some of the default ones that are already set by the operating system. To get a list of all the current enviroment variables open up a command prompt and enter `SET`. Or, programmatically, use [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable.aspx). All of those are usable in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is more and yes you can use a term.
E.g. Desktop folder is Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop
Have look at: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx